# Rewriting getter in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created property `@property (nonatomic) NSString *userPin;`

And i want to rewrite getter and setter for it. I assume that backing variable _userPin is automatically generated, but when i try to access it in getter:

```
-(NSString*)userPin{

    /* Minutes */

    _userPin;
}
```

However compiler warn me for undeclared identifier `_userPin`. Why is that variable not generated?

Comment: @JamesP it doesnt matter because i cant access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs: "If you implement both a getter and a setter for a readwrite property, or a getter for a readonly property, the compiler will assume that you are taking control over the property implementation and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically."

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html